# pandas map column data based on value from another column using if to determine which dict to use

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Person1', 'CT', 2017],
               ['Person2', 'FL', 2017],
               ['Person3', 'TX', 2017],
              ['Person1', 'TX', 2016]], columns=['Name', 'State', 'Year'])
```

And two mapping tables below:

```
state_map = {'CT': 'Connecticut', 'FL': 'Florida', 'TX':'Texas'}
state_map2 = {'CT': 'ABC-CT', 'FL': 'BBC-Florida', 'TX':'CDA-TX'}
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
    Name    State   Year
0   Person1   CT    2017
1   Person2   FL    2017
2   Person3   TX    2017
3   Person1   TX    2016
```

I would like to find a way to add a new column with values mapped using an if condition that determines whether to use values mapped from state_map or state_map2. So if df[df['Name']=='Person1'] then use state_map else use state_map2.

The final output should look like this:

```
    Name    State   Year   New_State_Name
0   Person1   CT    2017   Connecticut
1   Person2   FL    2017   BBC-Florida
2   Person3   TX    2017   CDA-TX
3   Person1   TX    2016   Texas
```

I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
df['New_State_Name'] = [state_map[x] if df[df['Name'] == 'Person1'] else 
state_map2[x] for x in df['State']]
```

I got an error that says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['New_State_Name'] = np.where(df['Name']=='Person1',df['State'].map(state_map),df['State'].map(state_map2))
```

Output:

```
      Name State  Year New_State_Name
0  Person1    CT  2017    Connecticut
1  Person2    FL  2017    BBC-Florida
2  Person3    TX  2017         CDA-TX
3  Person1    TX  2016          Texas
```

Comment: Thanks, this was so much simpler to do and it works well! I was just curious, was my logic incorrect in trying to use an if condition within a list comprehension?

Comment: Ambigous error happens when you compair a list to a value in a if statement, so what if part of this list returns True and part returns False, if doesn't know what to do.  So you have to use another method such as any() or all() resulting in logic if any() part of the list results in True or of all elements in the list True.

Comment: Thank you for your help!