# Use the .map() function depending on another columns value when there is mire than two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have the following dataframe:

```
    gene    sample     SQ            assay
0   FAM     coop1   842.400000        SIQ
1   FAM     2          NaN            SIQ 
2   HEX     2          NaN            EEK
3   FAM     3          NaN            SIQ
4   HEX     3        6.225000         TSI
```

I want to replace the values under `genes`according to these dictionaries:

```
SIQ_map = {'FAM':'qnrS','Texas Red':'IC','HEX':"Sul1"}
TSI_map = {'FAM':'blaSHV','Texas Red':'Int1','HEX':'TetB'}
MOA_map = {'FAM':'blaOXA','Texas Red':'Aph3a','HEX':'MecA'}
EEK_map = {'FAM':'','Texas Red':'','HEX':'blaKPC'}
BAM_map = {'FAM':'TetM','Texas Red':'VanB','HEX':'VanA'}
```

I've used the `.map()` function in dataframes with only one type of `assay`.
But how can I choose a different dictionary for mapping depending on the `assay` value, if there is more than one?

What I want is this output:

```
    gene    sample     SQ            assay
  0 qnrS    coop1   842.400000        SIQ
  1 qnrS    2          NaN            SIQ 
  2         2          NaN            EEK
  3 qnrS    3          NaN            SIQ
  4 TetB    3        6.225000         TSI
```

I saw using `np.where()` in another question, but this seems useful only for case with two conditions. In my case, I have 5 conditions (SIQ, TSI,MOA,EEK and BAM). How would I get the desired output in that case?

Comment: Hello Catalina. I believe this has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334020/pandas-map-column-data-based-on-value-from-another-column-using-if-to-determine).

Comment: @BoboDarph Thanks! I tried using the search function but used the wrong expression

Comment: Cu mare placere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
assay_map = {'SIQ': {'FAM':'qnrS','Texas Red':'IC','HEX':"Sul1"},
         'TSI': {'FAM':'blaSHV','Texas Red':'Int1','HEX':'TetB'},
         'MOA': {'FAM':'blaOXA','Texas Red':'Aph3a','HEX':'MecA'},
         'EEK': {'FAM':'','Texas Red':'','HEX':'blaKPC'},
         'BAM': {'FAM':'TetM','Texas Red':'VanB','HEX':'VanA'}}
```

This way you can address any gene based on assay. Now we can map the data.

```
df['New Column']=[a[g] for g,a in zip(df['gene'],df['assay'].map(m))]
```

Comment: I'm working on an update using map right now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a mapping. Works great.

Comment: This worked, thanks !

Comment: I was just wondering why you have to specify [0] at the end?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I realized it was a mistake. I had trouble accessing the returned array from the mapping so I accessed the first index. Unfortunately, that method will not reliably produce the results you need. I've instead updated my answer with a more reliable solution.